# Tv Series (Humans) - Do I have a False Memory?

Tags: episode-identification, humans

When the TV show "Humans" first aired, I caught a fraction of an episode while channel surfing. I've just watched Season 1 in a marathon session, and there's no sign of the scene I remember...

In the scene [something] has gone missing. Parents Joe & Laura ask Synth Anita / Mia about it, and she leads them directly to the missing object. After chastising her, we discover the item was actually stolen by daughter Mattie.

Does anyone else remember this? Am I remembering a scene that was actually in Season 2, were episodes edited [and this scene cut from the set I watched]? Did actress Gemma Chan, or someone who looks a lot like her, do a similar TV show? Or do I just have a massive case of "false memory" ?

Comment: He's starting to remember. Who's the the memory-wiping flashy-light thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only saw the first season, and I don't remember that scene, I think you have false memory :)

I don't think it is from the second season, as Mia take control of the body at the end of first season, and Anita doesn't exist anymore.

By the way, the series`Humans` is a remake of Swedish series `Real Humans`, maybe the scene you saw is from there?

Comment: Swedish version? Damn.  "Real Humans". I don't remember the characters speaking in Swedish, but I could have seen a version dubbed into English. Time to do research...

Comment: "Real Humans" it is: Season 1, episode 2 and about 51 minutes into the episode. Like I said, I remember it in English but it's possible the show was dubbed for English consumption.

Comment: Great, you got it ;)